# nginx rewrite если файл не существует

Tags: nginx

Имеется ссылка такого вида:

> domain.com/rw/image/12/56/99/180/31255312/bvywefgt5w1gh2s5tr.jpg

и надо чтобы проверить если файл

> domain.com/cache/12/56/99/31255312/bvywefgt5w1gh2s5tr.(jpg|png|gif)

существует то показать его, а если нет то показывать это

> domain.com/image.php?id=31255312&hash=bvywefgt5w1gh2s5tr

Обратите внимание на то что, там ещё проверяется расширение. В смысле если нету этого файла с расширением jpg то надо проверить есть ли с расширением png или gif.

Comment: я знаю про эту директиву, но не смог именно в этом случае применить . Можете на примере показать?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте директиву [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). Что-то вроде

```
location ~ ^/rw/image/(.+)/(\d+)/([a-z0-9]+)\.jpg$ {
    try_files /cache/$1/$2/$3.jpg
              /cache/$1/$2/$3.png
              /cache/$1/$2/$3.gif
              /image.php?id=$2&hash=$3
    ;
```

Comment: Только без `=404`. И там ещё `/180/` в исходном запросе нужно убирать.

Comment: `404` – это детали, ТС виднее, что отдавать, если всё сломалось. `180` я счёл опечаткой ТС, и поэтому предложил не copy-paste решение, а «что-то вроде».

Comment: Это не детали, это ошибка. В таком виде при ненайденных картинках отдастся исходный код файла `image.php`. Потому что внутренний редирект делается только на _последний_ аргумент,  а все остальные обрабатываются в текущем `location`.

Comment: блоки `location` могут содержать вложенные блоки. Здесь я *предполагаю*, что правила обработки `*.php` будут указаны **внутри** этого `location`, так же, как и правила для статики из кэша `location ~*  \.(jpg|png|gif)$ { expires 365d; }`.

Comment: Не поможет. nginx **не будет** искать новый `location` для файлов указанных в `try_files`